# How to execute dynamic multiple timed intervals from a DB store in Quartz.Net?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I'm having a hard time planning how to implement the architecture. The problem:

```
>  A user can save a number of profiles:
>     Name
>     URL
>     Time Interval
Name       | URL      |Time Interval
Sample1    |s.com     |5 mins
Sample2    |x.com     |2 mins
Sample3    |xxx.com   |7 mins
```

**Is there a way to execute multiple scheduled jobs from a DB Store using `Quartz.net`?**

I'm well aware of the performance using the DB Store and RAM store but I still have to go with the DB Store.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create multiple jobs for each requirement of different time intervals.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

You should create a class with the method which creates the job, you can pass the required values/params to the method like - Name, URL and Time Interval when the new profile is created or whenever the logic of your application requires the job to be created.